# Parallax effect with CSS transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, parallax

Is it possible to make parallax effect of background image with css transitions? Parallax should be slower than scrolling, so something do slowing is needed - is it possible to do it with css? Or if not, how best to do it with js/jquery?

I care about best performance script, because my webpage is little overloaded.

Could someone tell or show how to do it? I will be very grateful.

Comment: No because that parallax will work with scroll and css dont understand scroll events so with css we can make a simple fixed background effect but not an original parallax with moving front and background image for that you need to use js only :)

Comment: Ok, so how best to resolve it with js/jquery? (whereas the best performance)

Comment: If you really need a effect of moving background then we need to use some stong js aur a plugin according to you suitability but if you ok with similar parallax effect with fixed background then its so simple you just have to put a background image in css with `background-size:cover` property it will work fine. :)

Comment: Technically possible with CSS-only: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Comment: @GauravAggarwal, that is **absolutely not true** - see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS has a `perspective` property which you can combine with `zoom` to achieve an element "behind" or "in front of" other elements which will thus scroll at different speeds.

There are many resources about that, the one that @dwreck08 gave is one of the best: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Here's a quick replication:

```css
.parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 1px;
  perspective: 1px;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  color: white;
  background: url(http://cliparts.co/cliparts/pT5/A7L/pT5A7L8T9.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% auto;
}
.parallax__layer--back {
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  background: url(http://www.hdiphone6wallpapers.net/iphone-6-backgrounds/iphone-6-wallpapers-2/iphone-6-wallpapers-hd-100pb94q-1080x1920.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.parallax__layer--slow {
  transform: translateZ(-4px) scale(4);
  background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ZRDN2sugdrg/UXa1qeFfjYI/AAAAAAAAVjo/1m10L-jCIgo/s1600/starcraft_2_render7E0.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parallax {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.parallax__layer {
  padding: 75vh 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--slow">
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
  </div>
</div>
```

To control the scroll speed of each layer, change the `translateZ` and `scale` properties.

Comment: Looks pretty, but is it possible in this case to make background parallax effect (meaning in background is image with 100% width and specified height, and foreground is some content)? I'm just try'in to achieve it, but so far without effect.

Comment: Yes, you can put pretty much anything you like in those parallax blocks, no limitations.

Comment: Only one problem - when click on screen and drag to right, it scroll horizontally. Have any idea, how to prevent it? That issue is sometimes with left clicking and mouse wheel clicking.

Comment: Hah, thank you, but I just modified the code, all the kudos go to the author. I've noticed the scroll issue - it's on the original example as well. It has to do something with overflow-x.