# How to create the parallax effect in 2 uneven columns so they end even at the end?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, parallax

I just saw this 2-column trick on apple's website, and I think it's pretty cool.

Basically, they have two columns where one is longer than the other and when you scroll the page, one column slows down to catch up with the other so when you get to the end of the columns they line up at the bottom.

https://www.apple.com/macos/high-sierra-preview/

this is what i've got so far https://jsfiddle.net/yfembtfq/ columns work as they should and stop scrolling when they match the bottoms

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var marginvariant = $(window).scrollTop() * (($('#left').height() / $('#right').height()) * 0.16);
  marginvariant = Math.round(marginvariant);
  var $left = $('#left'); //record the elem so you don't crawl the DOM everytime
  var leftbottom = $('#left').height() - $left.position().top - marginvariant;
  var $right = $('#right'); //record the elem so you don't crawl the DOM everytime
  var rightbottom = $('#right').height() - $right.position().top;
  var bottomdif = leftbottom - rightbottom;
  if (bottomdif >= 0) {
    $('#left').css('margin-top', -marginvariant);
  }
});
```

however i need them to start the scrolling parallax effect only when they reach the top of the page not as soon as i start scrolling as you can see on JSFiddle

I've tried using a way to detect if they reach the top of the page but then the entire offset of objects is wrong... also i need to find a way to automatically calculate the final multiplier * 0.16 according to the height of the page and height of the columns, as this is what dictates the speed of the right column scroll so they kind of match at the end when the bottoms are visible.

Comment: This does not need lots of calculations. For the effect, pure CSS can achieve pretty amazing results. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964391/parallax-effect-with-css-transition#33964894 and for the animations, you just need to track the scroll position and animate your div when the scroll position is greater or less than that o your div's vertical position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love the effect from MacOS High Sierra website. So here's a link to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Carlos1162/full/EwZvBQ) where I found somewhat of a solution. Check it out and give me some feedback!

```
$(window).on("load resize scroll",function(e){
var col1 = $("#left").outerHeight();
var col2 = $("#right").outerHeight();
var travel = col1 - col2;

var topOfColumns = $('.parallax').offset().top;
var columns = $('.parallax').outerHeight() - $(window).innerHeight();
var scrollInterval = columns / travel;

    var e = Math.round( ($(window).scrollTop() - topOfColumns ) / scrollInterval);
    //find the bottom of the right column and give a Bool (true)
    var b = $(window).scrollTop() >= $('#right').offset().top + $('#right').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight;

    //if the user scrolls to the top of the columns and the user has not scrolled to the bottom of the right column
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= topOfColumns && b == false ) {
        $("#right").css({
            "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(0px, " + e + "px, 0px)",
               "-moz-transform": "translate3d(0px, " + e + "px, 0px)",
                "-ms-transform": "translate3d(0px, " + e + "px, 0px)",
                 "-o-transform": "translate3d(0px, " + e + "px, 0px)",
                      transform: "translate3d(0px, " + e + "px, 0px)"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: that's awesome! exactly what i was looking for

Comment: No problem. After I saw you were the only one asking this question I decided to give it a try. I'm sure there is someone here that can maybe make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use something similar to this https://medium.com/talk-like/detecting-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-jquery-a6a4405a3ea2 To check when the element is in view. I'm also trying to create this effect with 2 columns, but I don't find the way to achieve it... And can't find out any tutorial neither. Finally did you success to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying some stuff with the code you gave, and I was using an anchor ID to detect the moment to trigger the parallax when the anchor (the red line on the picture) is at the top of the window. In somehow it works, but for some reason it creates a jump of the left column the anchor is reached (as you can see on the picture I attached).

Here is the code:

```
var anchor_offset = $('#anchor').offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var marginvariant = $(window).scrollTop() * (($('#left').height() / $('#right').height()) * 0.16);
  marginvariant = Math.round(marginvariant);
  var $left = $('#left');
  var leftbottom = $('#left').height() - $left.position().top - marginvariant;
  var $right = $('#right');
  var rightbottom = $('#right').height() - $right.position().top;
  var bottomdif = leftbottom - rightbottom;

  if ( $(window).scrollTop() > anchor_offset && bottomdif >= 0) {
    $('#left').css('margin-top', -marginvariant);
  }
});
```

[Image of the anchor jump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXRvB.png)