# Adding scroll effects to a parallax scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added a simple parallax scroll to my website and I'd like to make it a bit smoother (smth like: bg image is scrolling slower than the actual website for example).

My parallax scrolling kinda looks like this:

```css
.parallax { 
    background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/FH6RSxbF/Bild-2.jpg");
    min-height: 200px; 
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-position: center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover; 
} 

.filler {
  background-color:blue;
  height: 500px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="filler"></div>
<div class="Bild parallax" id="wir-ueber-unsbild"><!--<img src="../images/Bild_5.png" width="1280px">--></div>
          <div class="bildschrift"><h1>Wir über uns</h1></div>
          <div class="content">
            <h3> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
            <h2> sit amet </h2>
            <p> consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</b></p>
          </div>
          <div class="filler"></div>
```

I tried looking up some solutions but most of them didn't fit with the rest of my code.
(for example: [Parallax effect with CSS transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964391/parallax-effect-with-css-transition))
I'm looking for something rather simple (could be JS or CSS)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic We are not here to do your research for you, or to write code for you. If you have no idea where to even start, then you need to go and do a bit more research first.